# Exponential inflation equations

Tags: math, economics

We are trying to model an exponentially inflationary currency exchange, let's say converting dollars into clams, based on a compounding rate.  Our cost equation looks like this:

c = b(b*r)^e

Where:
c is the cost of the next clam
b is the base cost of the first clam
r is the rate of inflation
e is the number of clams already in existence

This works well.  The first clam costs b, the second costs b * rate, and it goes exponential from there.  Perfect.

What we are trying to do now is figure out how many clams will be created, knowing a number of a dollars to be exchanged and the number of clams already in existence.

We are neither mathematicians nor economists, and this is kicking our butts.  Help would be greatly appreciated.  A minimum of scientific symbols would be appreciated as well -- I need to translate this into code, and my Greek is very rusty.  ;-)

Bonus points for correctly guessing what game I'm working on!  :-)

Comment: 1. You didn't mention about the programming language, 2. This is not a code-for-me service forum, 3. Had you tried on your own , you would have written some sensible piece of code yet!

Comment: The compounding rate formula usually is `b*(1+r)^e`, I can't imagine that your results look realistic over more than one scenario.

Comment: This could be solved with for-loops and subtracting the costs as you go along....unless you have absurdly low-inflation or low base cost.

Comment: The programming language shouldn't matter.  I'm not asking for programming help, I'm asking for math help.  I have tried on my own, we've tried on our own, we aren't getting it.

Comment: We did try the "standard" b*(1+r)^e but that didn't give us quite the result we wanted.  The tweaked equation does.  "Realism" is not a factor.

Comment: I did try to calculate using a loop, but calculating fractional clams from "remaining" dollars is a drag.  I'm guessing (naively) there is a way to convert the equation.

Answer (score 1):

In the comments, fractional units were mentioned. I will assume that you allow fractional sales, so a loop is not going to cut it.

Let's suppose that the instantaneous exchange rate after x units have been sold is a*s^x. That ^ is exponentiation, not bitwise XOR. The total cost of the v-u units from u to v can be found from calculus:

```
Integrate from u to v of a s^x dx
= (a/ln s) * (s^v - s^u)
```

I changed the notation for a few of the variables. e already has a meaning with exponentials. You used b for two things that turn out to be different. Normally, you do not expect to see (b * r)^... but rather r^... or (1+r)^... so I will just change to using s as the base of the exponential.

Given some amount of money m, we want to find v so that

```
(a/ln s) * (s^v - s^u) = m
s^v - s^u = (m * ln s)/a
s^v = ((m * ln s)/a + s^u)
v = log_s((m * ln s)/a + s^u)
v = ln ((m * ln s)/a + s^u) / ln s
```

For example, suppose the instantaneous cost after x units is $100 * (1.01)^x. How much can you buy with $1 million? 463.32. At that point, the instantaneous cost will be up to $10,050.

You might be surprised that if you have $100, and the instantaneous cost is $100, you can't buy 1 unit. You can buy 0.995058 units because the price isn't a constant $100. The second half of the first unit costs more than the first half, and with only $100 you can't afford to buy a whole unit. It is possible that you would want to specify not the instantaneous exchange rate, but the cost of the first item. The cost of the first item is (a/ln s)(s^1-s^0) = (a/ln s)(s-1), which is a little more than a, since s-1 is a little more than ln s. If you specify the cost of the first item b = a *(s-1)/ln s, you can compute a = b * (ln s)/(s-1). So, if you want the first item to cost $100 with s=1.01, the instantaneous cost at 0 items is $100 * (ln  1.01)/(.01) = $99.5033.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, Douglas.  You've given me a lot to chew on.